# Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127

Tags: python, hadoop

**mapper.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = line.strip().split(',')
    article_id = parts[0]
    section_text = parts[3]
    for term in section_text.split():
        print(f"{term}\t{article_id}")
```

**Reducer.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
current_term = None
article_ids = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    term, article_id = line.strip().split('\t')
    if current_term != term:
        if current_term:
            print(f"{current_term}\t{','.join(article_ids)}")
       
        current_term = term
        article_ids = []
    article_ids.append(article_id)
if current_term:
    print(f"{current_term}\t{','.join(article_ids)}")
```

**Error:**

```
2024-03-15 17:15:20,282 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1710516647105_0007_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
***Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127***
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172
```

)

**Command:**

```
hadoop jar /home/tashi/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.6.jar \
    -input hdfs:///assignment/enwiki-20170820.csv \
    -output /input/output7 \
    -mapper mapper.py \
    -reducer reducer.py \
    -file /home/tashi/mapper.py \
    -file /home/tashi/reducer.py
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.